# Assigning and checking at the same time and having a nice Syntax Error

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to reproduce a language parser from the Eloquent Javascript book at Chapter 11. See [here](http://eloquentjavascript.net/11_language.html).

When I try to do that:

```
function parseExpression(program) {
  program = skipSpace(program);
  var match, expr;
  if (match = /^"([^"]*)"/.exec(program))
    expr = {type: "value", value: match[1]};
  else if (match = /^\d+\b/.exec(program))
    expr = {type: "value", value: Number(match[0])};
  else if (match = /^[^\s(),"]+/.exec(program))
    expr = {type: "word", name: match[0]};
  else
    throw new SyntaxError("Unexpected syntax: " + program);

  return parseApply(expr, program.slice(match[0].length));
}
```

I get a very strange `SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input` from the `if`.

However, a dummy assignation like `if (str = 'my string')` works perfectly.
Is the Regex messing with that behavior?

Edit: I tried to debug using the console. Here is what I get:

```
$ node
> .load parser.js
> function parseExpression(program) {
...   program = skipSpace(program);
...   var match, expr;
...   if ((match = /^"([^"]*)"/.exec(program)))
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
    at Object.exports.createScript (vm.js:24:10)
    at REPLServer.defaultEval (repl.js:225:25)
    at bound (domain.js:287:14)
    at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:300:12)
    at REPLServer.<anonymous> (repl.js:417:12)
    at emitOne (events.js:82:20)
    at REPLServer.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at REPLServer.Interface._onLine (readline.js:210:10)
    at REPLServer.Interface._line (readline.js:549:8)
    at REPLServer.Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:884:20)
>     expr = {type: "value", value: match[1]};
ReferenceError: match is not defined
    at repl:1:31
    at REPLServer.defaultEval (repl.js:252:27)
    at bound (domain.js:287:14)
    at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:300:12)
    at REPLServer.<anonymous> (repl.js:417:12)
    at emitOne (events.js:82:20)
    at REPLServer.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at REPLServer.Interface._onLine (readline.js:210:10)
    at REPLServer.Interface._line (readline.js:549:8)
    at REPLServer.Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:884:20)
>   else if (match = /^\d+\b/.exec(program))
...     expr = {type: "value", value: Number(match[0])};
...   else if (match = /^[^\s(),"]+/.exec(program))
SyntaxError: Unexpected token else
    at Object.exports.createScript (vm.js:24:10)
    at REPLServer.defaultEval (repl.js:225:25)
    at bound (domain.js:287:14)
    at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:300:12)
    at REPLServer.<anonymous> (repl.js:417:12)
    at emitOne (events.js:82:20)
    at REPLServer.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at REPLServer.Interface._onLine (readline.js:210:10)
    at REPLServer.Interface._line (readline.js:549:8)
    at REPLServer.Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:884:20)
>     expr = {type: "word", name: match[0]};
ReferenceError: match is not defined
    at repl:1:29
    at REPLServer.defaultEval (repl.js:252:27)
    at bound (domain.js:287:14)
    at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:300:12)
    at REPLServer.<anonymous> (repl.js:417:12)
    at emitOne (events.js:82:20)
    at REPLServer.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at REPLServer.Interface._onLine (readline.js:210:10)
    at REPLServer.Interface._line (readline.js:549:8)
    at REPLServer.Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:884:20)
>   else
...     throw new SyntaxError("Unexpected syntax: " + program);
...   return parseApply(expr, program.slice(match[0].length));
... }
```

Comment: what is the `program` stand for?

Comment: `/^"([^"]*)"/`  this is your problem

Comment: My line of code was already verifiable in the node console. If you try to evaluate the `if` you will get a Syntax Error

Comment: @Mr.White can you explain please?

Comment: What usually fixes this kind of error is wrapping it in _another_ set of braces, so the assignment gets evaluated _before_ the if statement: `if ((match = /^"([^"]*)"/.exec(program))) {` - This works in the browser as well, and it makes sense as the `=` assignment operator is not really expected inside an if statement, but it will work in any random brackets.

Comment: What Node version are you using? I simply cannot reproduce it with mine (v5.7.0 on Win64).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node appears to have a problem with the `"` chars in the regexp.
By escaping them the function parses correctly.

```
function parseExpression(program) {
  program = skipSpace(program);
  var match, expr;
  if ((match = /^\"([^\"]*)\"/.exec(program)))
    expr = {type: "value", value: match[1]};
}
```

Comment: I also escaped my double quote in the third `if`. Didn't know you have to escape double quotes in that case. Many thx

Comment: Your original code works fine in the Chrome browser. You should not need to escape `"`. I suspect a node bug or incompatibility.

Comment: yeah! I tried it on node v4 and v5 tho and escaping double quote is mandatory.

Comment: @HBP - I agree it must be a Node bug. Original code is valid JavaScript and does run fine in my copy of Node (v5.7.0 on Win64). Whatever, it's always good to have a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong in your code:

```
C:\test>node -v
v5.7.0

C:\test>node
> .load parser.js
> function parseExpression(program) {
...   program = skipSpace(program);
...   var match, expr;
...   if (match = /^"([^"]*)"/.exec(program))
...     expr = {type: "value", value: match[1]};
...   else if (match = /^\d+\b/.exec(program))
...     expr = {type: "value", value: Number(match[0])};
...   else if (match = /^[^\s(),"]+/.exec(program))
...     expr = {type: "word", name: match[0]};
...   else
...     throw new SyntaxError("Unexpected syntax: " + program);
...
...   return parseApply(expr, program.slice(match[0].length));
... }
undefined
>
```

If it doesn't work for you I'd say it's a Node bug that affects your version (you don't say which one exactly), maybe [#5113 repl cannot handle single quote in regex, when within a function](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/5113)):

> I'm getting a 'SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input' when I try to
>   enter the following in the repl
>
> ```
> var someFunction = function(s) {
>     s = s.replace(/'/g, '');
> }
> ```
>
> However, `s = s.replace(/'/g, '')` by itself on a new line is OK. Am I
>   doing something wrong?

That bug was fixed on [Node/5.7.0](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/v5.7.1/CHANGELOG.md#2016-02-23-version-570-stable-rvagg).

Comment: many thanks! I tried this code on 4.2.4 and 5.3.0 but didn't tried it with more since I have some dependencies in my project.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue trying to run this code on Node v6.10.3. Ended up working when I escaped the quotes inside the regular expressions as others have stated.